# Error in my calculations for a y2k38 count down

Tags: java

Hey I need to make a program that counts down the days/ hours/ min/ sec until y2k38 i got the code but I have a logic error and am getting the wrong number for hours mins and secs. Heres my code:

```
public class Assignment1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
// The problem will occur at 2^31 seconds
long y2k38 = (long) Math.pow(2, 31)*1000;
// Assigning the time intervals values based on eachother 
long diffsec = (y2k38-now)/1000;
long diffmin = diffsec/60;
long diffhours = diffmin/60;
long diffdays = diffhours/24;
// issuing a print statement to output the days,hours..etc until y2k38
System.out.printf(
    "%d days\n"+
    "%d hours\n"+
    "%d minutes\n"+
    "%d seconds\n",
    (diffdays),(diffmin%60), (diffsec%3600),(diffsec%60));  
}

}
```

Comment: What's the error? What values are you getting? And what are you expecting?

Comment: `diffsec % 3600` gives you a value from 0 to 3599; is that really what you want to print for "minutes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are all very strange, you can modify and print them as follows:

```
    long diffsecs  = (y2k38 - now) / 1000;
    long diffmins  = (diffsecs / 60) % 60;
    long diffhours = (diffsecs / 60 / 60) % 24;
    long diffdays  = diffsecs / 60 / 60 / 24;
    diffsecs       = diffsecs % 60;

    System.out.printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, d seconds\n",
        diffdays, diffhours, diffmins, diffsecs);
```

This gives you something like:

```
8126 days, 22 hours, 42 minutes, 21 seconds
```

which roughly matches what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the difference into total days/hours/mins/secs. Instead, you want to start with finding days, and use the reminder to find hours, and so on.

```
long diff = y2k38 - now;
long diffdays = diff/(24*60*60*1000);
diff = diff%(24*60*60*1000);
long diffhours = diff/(60*60*1000);
diff = diff%(60*60*1000);
long diffmin = diff/(60*1000);
diff = diff%(60*1000);
long diffsec = diff/1000;
```

Also it's faster to compute the y2k38 value by

```
long y2k38 = ((long)(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1)*1000;
```